# python regular expression to extract file_name from a given directory path

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have some folders like-so:

```
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02085620-Chihuahua
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02085782-Japanese_spaniel
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02086910-papillon
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02088466-bloodhound
....
....
```

I want to extract only these info's`(Chihuahua, Japanese_spaniel, papillon, bloodhound)` from the paths of the files using `Python`.
Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` here

**Ex:**

```
s = """../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02085620-Chihuahua
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02085782-Japanese_spaniel
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02086910-papillon
../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02088466-bloodhound
"""

for p in s.splitlines():
    print(p.split("-")[-1])
```

---

If you need regex.

```
import re

for p in s.splitlines():
    print(re.search(r"\-(\w+)$", p).group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
Chihuahua
Japanese_spaniel
papillon
bloodhound
```

Comment: Thanks I was actually looking for a `regex` solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common factors.

- Image folder paths are same

  - For instance: all image starts with *../dog_breeds/images/Images/*
  - `replace('../dog_breeds/images/Images/', '')` for removing the paths
- All images start with 10-character

  - For instance: *n02085620-*, *n02085782-*
  - `replace('../dog_breeds/images/Images/', '')[10:]` for removing the characters.

If we combine the two factors:

```py
res = ['../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02085620-Chihuahua',
       '../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02085782-Japanese_spaniel',
       '../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02086910-papillon',
       '../dog_breeds/images/Images/n02088466-bloodhound']

part1 = [r.replace('../dog_breeds/images/Images/', '')[10:] for r in res]
print(part1)
```

Output is:

```
['Chihuahua', 'Japanese_spaniel', 'papillon', 'bloodhound']
```